# set selected value after jQuery populated Dropdownlist using dwr

Tags: javascript, dwr

I have a dropdown for which I load values using dwr call and highlight a value available in database. My problem is, it shows the first value of dropdown instead of the value I fetch from database. If I keep refreshing, sometimes correct values come.

Below is the code which I used.

```
$('select[name="name"] option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() == data.name;
}).attr("selected", true);
```

I checked the value in alert, the `data.name` works properly, but when setting is `selected=true,` it is wrong.

Comment: maybe you calling this function before dwr returned the value, can you post your code together with the dwr function ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope, It will work fine

```
$('select[name="name"]').val(data.name)
```

EDIT

```
if($('select[name="name"]').val(data.name).val() ==  data.name){
   // value exist in drop down
}else{
  //NOT exist 
}
```

The `filter` iterate all the `select option` and compare each option, that would be slow

Comment: data.name is the value from DB. So I make a check here if that value exists in the dropdown. $(this).val() is the values present in dropdown. If present I set that selected. Won't it be like skipping the check in the case you have mentioned ?

Comment: @sahana, OK if the value `data.name` is exist in drop-down then selected otherwise not select(select first option), check updated code

Comment: @ Girish Still value changes. in alert box data.name comes correct as it is in the database. But when selecting in dropdown, first value gets selected sometimes. If I refresh again and again, it comes correct. Again on refresh, it goes out.